# Java, Creating a calendar

Tags: java, calendar

In my Java class, I have to build a calendar application.  I've got it mostly completed, however I need help with a couple of methods.  I have commented the parts that I need help with.  The code includes three classes and a main called TestCalendar.  The functions I need help with are located in the Calendar class, named removeEvent(two of them, taking two different arguments), printEvents, and findEvents. Thanks in advance!

Here is the Date class.

```
            public class Date {
    int year, month, day;
    //constructor
    public Date(int yr, int mth, int dy){
    year = yr;
    if (yr < 2000  || yr > 2100)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Calander Year");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    month = mth;
    if (mth < 1 || mth > 12)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Month");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    day = dy;
    if (dy < 1 || dy > 31)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong Day");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    }
    //accessor methods
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }
    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
    //returns date in correct format
    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
    }
```

Here is the Event class

```
    public class Event {
    Date date;
    int hour;
    String activity;

    Event(int year, int month, int day, int hour, String activity)
    {
        if (year < 2000  || year > 2100)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Calander Year");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Month");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (day < 1 || day > 31)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Day");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        this.date = new Date(year, month, day);
        this.hour = hour;
        this.activity = activity;

    }
    public Date getDate()
    {
    return date;    
    }
    public int getHour()
    {
        return hour;    
    }
    public String getActivity()
    {
        return activity;
    }
    void setActivity(String newActivity) 
    {
        this.activity = newActivity;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
    return "" + date +" " + "@" + hour +":" + " " + activity;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
    if (obj instanceof Event)   
    {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
    }
    }
```

The Calendar class

```
    public class Calander {
        static final int MAXEVENTS = 10;
        Event[] events;
        int numEvents;

        // constructor
        public Calander() {
            numEvents = 0;
            events = new Event[MAXEVENTS];
        }

        void addEvent(int year, int month, int day, int hour, String activity) {
            Event newEvent = new Event(year, month, day, hour, activity);
            events[numEvents] = newEvent;
            numEvents++;
        }


        void removeEvent(int year, int month, int day, int hour, String activity) {


            {
             if (events[numEvents] == null);
             numEvents--;    
            }
        }

        // instructions say to remove (all) Event objects in the Calendar that are equals to the event argument.  Use the equals method from the event class

        void removeEvent(Event event) {

    //what to put here?
        }

        // this method needs to print every Event in the associated Calendar that matches the date arguments.  Print each on a separate line, using the toString method from the Event class.

        void printEvents(int year, int month, int day) { // how to set equality
    if (this.events[numEvents] == )
            {
                // what to put here?
            }
        }

        // same as above but matches the (Date date) arguments
        void printEvents(Date date) {
                toString();
        }

        // Return the first Event in the Calendar that has a matching (equals) activity field.  If no match is found, you must return a reference type, so return null.

                    Event findEvent(String activity) {
                            //what to put here?
            return null;
        }


        void dump() {

            for (int i = 0; i < MAXEVENTS; i++)
            {
                if (events[i] != null)
                System.out.println(events[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be homework, so please tag it as such.

Comment: Actually we're not supposed to be doing homework...

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob No, but if it is homework, we could give some useful hints. We will not (and should not) give him the solution though of course.

Comment: @brimborium well yeah I guess

Answer (score 2):

well, your event class has a method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

Which, presumably, should return whether or not the passed event is equal to the instance.

So your `void removeEvent(Event event)` method should look similar to the following:

**take note that this is psudo-code and not valid java.  you're going to have to flesh out the details on your own.**

```
void removeEvent(Event event) 
{
    foreach(event e in this.events)
    {
        if(event.equals(e))
        {
            // remove e from the events array
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the methods are going to more or less be similar in concept to the first one with 2 varying factorrs:

- how you identify a match
- what you do with the match

Comment: Yay for giving him a push in the right direction and not the whole answer.

Comment: void removeEvent(Event event) 
   {
    for (Event e; this.events)
    if (this.events.equals(e))
    {
       numEvents--;
    }
    
   }

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I don't actually want to do your homework. So as a hint, you want to use (your event).equals(comparing to other event), not "==".

Comment: Not sure why it will not format the code properly, but i am having a little bit of an issue with the for statement.  I realize that the for statement its in the form for(intialize, test, update) but I'm not sure how to translate that into this method.  I understand (at least I think) that the initialization is Event e, and that it needs to test this.events, however I do not know what I should put for the update part.  Also I get a type mismatch.   void removeEvent(Event event) 
   {
    for (Event e; this.events)
    if (this.events.equals(e))
    {
       numEvents--;
    }
    
   }

Comment: Oops, didn't realize pressing enter would comment.

What the answer above mine is telling you to do, is to go through every element in the array of events, then compare each event to the event you're trying to remove. Then if they are equal, then remove that event from that array.

Actually as stated above, you'd want to use what's called a for each loop. It's formatted like this: for(initialization of an object : an array of those objects)

So for example with a case of Integer objects, 
Integer[] numbers = new Integer[5]; 
for(Integer i:numbers)
{
//Stuff
}